# Resetting TCP/IP Settings on Windows 8

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, tcpip, netsh

Apparently, there's a command:

```
netsh int ip reset
```

which resets TCP/IP settings for Windows XP/Vista/7, but I'm not sure that it works correctly on Windows 8.

[image: cmd screenshot]

When I typed the command under command prompt (Admin) I got two errors as pointed out in the screenshot:

```
Resetting , failed.  
Access is denied.
```

At the end it said `Resetting , OK!`, so how do I confirm if it worked or not?

Comment: Just double checking, are you sure you were in an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @Keltari: Yes, you can also notice that on the title bar of command prompt in the screenshot where it says "Administrator: Command Prompt".

Answer (score 3):

run [ProcMon](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WCA-B306) in background while runing the command and filter for `Access Denied` errors in the Result column.

Comment: When I ran this it stated that it was HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a00-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\26 that netsh was getting access denied on. Added permissions to this reg key, and it worked.

Comment: nice to hear that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've run this command on a lot of customers' PCs, and despite the error message, the command has always done its job. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the command to say why it produces an error message.